# clearInterval not working from interval inside setTimeout

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

Clear interval is not working for an interval i use inside setTimeout().

```
var $scroller;

setTimeout(function() {
    var div = jQuery('.module-content-slider');
    $scroller = setInterval(function(){
        /* interval function */
    }, 25)
}, 1000);

 clearInterval($scroller);
```

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: Is that the actual code? You expect clearInterval to cancel the interval that has yet to be created? Do you understand that the code after the timeout runs before the code inside the setTimeout executes. The setTimeout is not a sleep command.

Comment: For your code to work as you expect it to, callback function of `setTimeout` should execute before `clearInterval` is called BUT that's not how your code executes. Callback function of `setTimeout` will execute _after_ `clearInterval` has been called. This means that by the time `clearinterval` is called, `$scroller` is still undefined - you are trying to clear an interval that hasn't been created yet.

Answer (score 4):

The `clearInterval` runs before `setInterval` within the "`timeout`" after 1 second (`1000` milliseconds) is executed — effectively clearing an unset `$scroller` interval.

Answer (score 1):

There is no what to clear.
The interval doesn't exist at `clearInterval($scroller);` run time.
`clearInterval` will be executed a second later.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your use case is to trigger interval function for every 25 ms and clear the interval after 1000 ms.

If thats the scenario then it should be

```
var $scroller = setInterval(function(){
        /* interval function */
    }, 25);

setTimeout(function() {
    var div = jQuery('.module-content-slider');
    clearInterval($scroller);
}, 1000);
```